# Is it correct to use only Past and Present Simple in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a sentence told by a native English speaker:

> When Southern California-based food and lifestyle expert
> was pregnant with her daughter, she knew she didn't just want an
> ordinary baby shower - you know, a standard tame afternoon where
> everyone sat politely and watched her open presents.

My questions are:

1. *"...where everyone sat politely and watched..."* - is it correct? The sentence is all about an imaginary situation, should the speaker have said *"where everyone would sit and watch"* ?
2. *"...watched her open presents"* - is it correct? Why Present Simple was chosen, instead of *"watched her opening"* or *"watched her opened"*?

Comment: _Watched her opened_ is incorrect. _Open_ is not the present tense (which would be _opens_), it is the infinitive. _Opening_  would be acceptable too.  See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing).

Comment: @KateBunting , thank you for a useful link, it made it clearer for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct.

In the first instance, although the party didn't exist, it has been established as an event. There is no conditional aspect to it.

Had it been expressed conditionally: *"If there was such a party, people would sit and watch her open presents"*, then you would indeed need 'would watch'.

In the second case, simple present is normal English usage *in the given context.*

Comment: thanks! the absence of an conditional aspect in the sentence was something elusive for me

Answer (score 0):

**1**...where everyone sat politely and watched...' is correct. It is not a conditional sentence.

**2.** "...watched her **open** presents" is correct. We can also say ...watched her **opening** presents.

We can use an infinitive form or the -ing form after see, **watch**, notice, hear etc.

I saw him *cross* the road. I saw him *crossing* the road.